# Excel formula to lookup a table from another table with comma separated output

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get a formula that looks up information from another table and populates the output with comma separated values. As shown below, I want to populate column D in Table 2 with information from Table 1. The desired output is in column E. I came up with this formula but it's only pulling one city per person.

TEXTJOIN(", ",,INDEX('Table 1'!B:B,MATCH(FILTERXML(""&SUBSTITUTE(C3,",","")&"","//m"),'Table 1'!A:A,0)))

[image]

[image]

Comment: switch the first and second criteria in the MATCH and limit the range to the data and use FILTER instead of INDEX.:  `TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER('Table 1'!B$2:B$9,ISNUMBER(MATCH('Table 1'!A$2:A$9,FILTERXML(""&SUBSTITUTE(C3,",","")&"","//m"),0))))`

Comment: @ScottCraner, this did not work for me. I keep getting a #calc error. Also, note that it'll be better if the range is not defined. That is, A:A and not A2:A9. That way, I don't have to modify the formula if new rows are added to Table 1. Thoughts?

Comment: @SammieDave if you are not defining the range then I would ask you to use a `Table Structure Reference` where you dont have to define the range in your formula, aslo it doesnt takes the blank cells into consideration in your formula which reduces the excel engine speed

Comment: Thanks! It appears to be working now. However, there is one down side that I am hoping you can help with. If there is only one person listed, it's returning a #calc error. This formula only appear to be working when there are multiple staff present. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: @SammieDave see I have updated in answers

Answer (score 2):

For you reference, you can see the screenshot below,

[image]

---

Solution as posted by **[Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner)** Sir using `FILTERXML()`

• Formula used in cell `G8`

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER($B$3:$B$9,ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$3:$A$9,FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(F3,", ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"),0)),""))
```

---

**Note:** Depending on one's Excel version this may needs to be keyed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

---

Perhaps, if you are using MS365 then you can use `ARRAYTOTEXT()` with `TEXTSPLIT()` as well,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `G3`

```
=ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER($B$3:$B$9,ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$3:$A$9,TEXTSPLIT(F3,,", ",1),0)),""))
```

---

Kindly change the cell range/sheet preferences as per your suit.

---

### Edit

> Thanks! It appears to be working now. However, there is one down side that I am hoping you can help with. If there is only one person listed, it's returning a #calc error. This formula only appear to be working when there are multiple staff present. Any idea on how to fix this?

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `G8`

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(B:B,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A:A,FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(F8&", ",", ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"),0))))
```

Or,

• Formula used in cell `G3`

```
=ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER($B:$B,ISNUMBER(MATCH($A:$A,TEXTSPLIT(F3&", ",,", ",1),0)),""))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `D3`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH("*, "&A$3:A$9&", *",", "&C3&", ",2)),B$3:B$9,""))
```

Note I concatenated leading/trailing comma/space's to prevent possible false positives.

Also, in case you wish to avoid duplicates, just nest `UNIQUE()` in there:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,UNIQUE(IF(ISNUMBER(XMATCH("*, "&A$3:A$9&", *",", "&C3&", ",2)),B$3:B$9,"")))
```